# Security and code execution

Tags: programming-practices

If I am taking data from a website, for example status updates from Facebook and showing them on my website. What possible damage can be caused if I am not taking into account that the code written as status update would execute on my website?

For example,
Mr. Simon has putted his status update,

```
"<p style="color:red;">I love to code</p>"
```

Now, when I display this on my website, it transforms into the text **I love to code** written in red.

Comment: Is you question just "What damage can an xss vulnerability cause?"?

Answer (score 2):

Basically you will be vulnerable to XSS - the element might as well be a script element or the paragraph element could have an `onmouseover` etc attributes to run a script.

- If you are not using HttpOnly session cookies, XSS can be used to steal sessions.
- All security measures against CSRF are useless if you are vulnerable to XSS.
- The script can dynamically load malicious java, flash, pdf etc plugin files, which can exploit bugs in the respective browser plugins.
- The script can redirect the user somewhere else, hide your page or make for a convincing phishing page since it's on your domain.
- Probably many more - only your imagination is the limit :)